# testing references

Tags: php

```
echo 'test';

class createdclass {
    public $name;
}

class testc {
    function &testm(){
        $myvar =& new createdclass();
        return $myvar;
    }
}

$testo = new testc();

$a =& $testo->testm();
$a->name = 'Douglas';

$b =& $testo->testm();
$b->name = 'Scott';

echo $a->name;
echo $b->name;
```

myvar is a reference to an object
a and b are references to the same object
I changed a, then I changed b, but a wasn't changed by b
Why?

Comment: They don't look like "references to the same object" to me. Every time you call that "testm" function, a new instance of "createdclass" is created.

Comment: Sorry, not adding this as an answer because I may be wrong, but why should A and B reference the same object? You create a new `createdclass` for each - two separate objects...

Comment: Using `&` with objects probably doesn't do what you want (in PHP5; the same is not true for PHP4).  I suggest not using `&` unless you *need* references.

Comment: @strager In PHP5 objects are passed by reference by default anyway.  So the only way to *avoid* references is to use the `clone` operator.  So really there's no difference between using `= &$obj` and `= $obj`.  They behave the same (For object types)...

Comment: @Pointy - You know, we should have just posted our comments as answers. Then one of us would be up 55 points right now :p.

Comment: @ircmaxell, That's not true; there's a big difference between *object references* and *variable references*.  Refer to the documentation for more details.

Comment: Well, yes there is a difference.  But `$foo = $bar; $foo->name = 'bar'; echo $bar->name;` will output `bar`.  So there is a reference to the object.  While it's not a variable reference, the functionality is pretty much the same (so long as you don't reassign the variable itself)...

Comment: @Stephen well the thing is I don't actually know php, though I guess however tarnished php's reputation might be it'd be hard to imagine how it could be so broken as to not work the way the code clearly appears to work!

Comment: @Pointy: Yeah, same here. I wasn't 100% sure I was right, but if I had been wrong I might have cried at how wrongly PHP worked. XD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code each call to `testm()` creates a new instance of createdclass. So $a and $b aren't the same object.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first off, you shouldn't use `$myvar =& new ...`.  It's a [deprecated syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.deprecated.php) and is completely unnecessary (Since there's nothing to reference to)...

Secondly, you don't need the `=&` operator in the lines `$a =& $testo->testm()`.  The fact that the method returns a reference is good enough.  Not to mention that objects are passed by reference by default anyway, so you really don't **need** those lines anyway.  I put them in the method signature `function &foo()` mainly for readability (to show that we're expecting the return to be a reference)...

Third, the problem is what you're referencing.  References bind to a variable.  When you leave the scope, since `$myvar` is a local variable (and as such is garbage collected -- it is deleted -- when the method exits), the bound reference disappears.  So if you want that to work, you need to persist that variable.

Here's one example that works:

```
class testc {
    protected $createdclass = null;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->createdclass = new CreatedClass();
    }
    public function &testm() {
        return $this->createdclass;
    }
}

$tester = new testc;
$a = $tester->testm();
$a->name = 'foo';
$b = $tester->testm();
echo $b->name; //displays "foo"...
```

Answer (score 1):

in your example, a and b do not reference the same object because you create a new one in the  `testm()` function.

here is a short example that might clarify things a little:

```
<?php

class createdclass {
    public $name;
}

$a = new createdclass();
$a->name = 'Douglas';

// make $b reference the same as $a, i.e. let $p point to the same content as $a
$b = &$a;
$b = new createdclass();
$b->name = 'Scott';

echo $a->name;
echo $b->name;

?>
```

this will output `ScottScott`

if you want to learn more about references in php i'd recommend to read [References Explained](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) in the php manual